# Use of closure passed into a function causes a malloc crash

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have a custom UIView controller that I init like so:

```
inputPhoneNumberView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 286, height: 73)
let alert = SAAlertView(title: "Enter Your Phone Number", message: "Enter or update your phone number and we will send you a verification code via SMS.", customView: inputPhoneNumberView)
alert.addAction("Confirm", style: .default, dismissAfterAction: false, hasLoadingIndicator: true) { () -> Void in
    print("Hello!") //Testing code
}
alert.addAction(NSLocalizedString("cancel", comment: ""), style: .cancel, actionBlock: nil)
present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Actions can be added to the view controller that are associated to UIButtons inside it. e.g. `alert.addAction(NSLocalizedString("cancel", comment: ""), style: .cancel, actionBlock: nil`

An action is a struct defined as so:

```
struct Action {
        var title: String
        var style: ActionStyle
        var actionBlock: (() -> Void)?
        var dismissAfterAction: Bool
        var hasLoadingIndicator: Bool
    }
```

The code block in an action is handled in this method:

```
fileprivate dynamic func doAction(_ sender: CustomButton) {

        // Make sure the action should be allowed for default only.

        let action = actions[sender.tag]

        guard sender.tag >= 0 && sender.tag < actions.count else {
            print("No action at that index.", logType: .Error)
            return
        }

        if let block = action.actionBlock {
            if action.dismissAfterAction {
                dismiss(animated: true, completion: { 
                    block()
                })
            } else {

                block() // The point the crash occurs!
            }
        } else {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

There is an option when creating an action to `dismissAfterAction` i.e. auto dismiss the view controller then perform the code block. However if `dismissAfterAction` is `false` the app will crash with a `malloc error`. It doesn't always crash but if I repeatedly tap the button associated with that action it will eventually. Not sure what's going on here. Has anyone come across anything like this before? Seems to be a problem with the code block.

Comment: Can you post any of the crash log? I would check out what your actually doing in that closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had likely issue, some time ago. As a fix you can change your code in this way:

```
        //we already checked action block, so 
        action.actionBlock!()
        //block()  The point the crash occurs!
```

Comment: wow that works! why does it work though? why can't I use `block` from the let statement?

Comment: I don't know for now, I should add this to investigations stack.